# Fetching email from shared preferences inside NavaigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I m following android tutorial of navigation drawer but i fail display images in the nav header

http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html/
How can i add a profile picture and email address inside Navigation Drawer?
Below is navigation Header

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="178dp"
    android:background="#FF00CC"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="56dp"
                  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

                  <!-- Name-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usernameprofile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="kevin@gmail.com"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile_sample"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:id="@+id/circleView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigation Drawer header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/profile"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="abc@gmai.com"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Screen in which your navigation drawer is

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.uowd.sport.app.MainScreen">
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#004f71"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <include
            layout="@layout/header.xml"
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```